# Given a rectangle (4 vertices), how to make ONLY ONE of the corner rounded

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image]

You can apply Subdivision Surface modifier to round all corners but it will result in all corners being rounded.

[image]

How do I make it such that only ONE corner is rounded?

Is it possible?

Comment: okay. but thats like rounding corner"s"  in general. This is specific to one corner. So for my case when I was searching for existing solution I didn't think that question, from the title, would answer my specific question. This may help quite a lot of people.

Comment: Well, it's always best to generalize the search criteria a bit. Else we might have questions for rounding exactly 2 corners, 3 corners, etc. The site would be a mess. Duplicates help to organize it and this is a textbook example of one - note the question does not go to waist and it's not a bad thing to happen, users are redirected to the general one where more solutions are answered. Grouping like that helps with site coherence and helps other people to get there when they searched a bit differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a bevel modifier defined by a vertex group with only one vert selected.

[image: apple bevel modifier to a vert]

Comment: Haha, I literally learned how to do this yesterday :D